# Abstraction Vs. Interface Confusion

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, abstract-class

*Wait, before you start thinking, I would like to clear that I am **NOT** going to ask the routine differences between Interface and Abstract.*

I had gone through the difference between Abstract and Interface in [MSDN](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&ei=wcETUN7RHYX4rQf2yYDYCg&usg=AFQjCNETMTxWBiRrevXYVUyhAUj8sBDAbw).

It is said :

> *By updating the base class, all inheriting classes are automatically updated with the change.*
>   *Interfaces, on the other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of
>    an interface is required, you must create a whole new interface.*

See this : -
[image: Difference between Abstract and Interface]

Can anyone prove this using following example: -

```
abstract class WashingMachine
{
   abstract public void Wash();
}


class Philips : WashingMachine
{
   public Philips() {  }

   override public void Wash(){//Wash code here....}
}

class Samsung : WashingMachine
{
   public Samsung() {  }

   override public void Wash(){//Wash code here....}
}

class Videocon : WashingMachine
{
   public Videocon() {  }

   override public void Wash(){//Wash code here....}
}
```

Now, If I added following new abstract method in **WashingMachine** : -

```
abstract public void Rinse(int loadSize);
```

How all inheriting classes (i.e. Philips/Samsung/Videocon) will ***automatically*** get updated with the change?

Comment: All inheriting classes will automatically get updated if the method 'Rinse' is virtual not abstract.

Comment: @Mert, Clarify your point. it doesn't makes any sense. Even if you define Rinse as virtual, it won't get updated automatically, you have to override  the method in derived or else it be treated as implemented method of abstract class, where you  don't need to specify "virtual" keyword

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "update". If you define it as virtual and provide a default logic, then all the derived classes can both use the default logic or can override it.

Comment: @Mert, fine I understood, so it is again related to non-abstract method which others has highlighted....Thanks for your input....it helped me a lot to understand what exactly MSDN mean in that article. Hope, MSDN could be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They won't get updated - you still have to *manually* add an implementation of `Rinse` to each and every class that inherits from `WashingMachine`.

What I believe the MSDN says is that if you have a non-abstract method defined in an abstract class and you change *that* method, all classes that inherit from the abstract class will benefit from the change automatically.

Comment: I guess you are right, in that article they are talking about non-abstract methods defined in an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Your concrete derived types all need to provide an implementation of any inherited abstract member...thus your types will still need to provide a Rinse implementation when you modified the base.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusion programmers normally get when read difference between interface and abstract class. the line you refer is only true if the change in the abstract class is concrete. what i mean is you added a property or a method with implementation. Or if i am more specific, any change in base abstract class which does not make any concrete class abstract. Such change is possible  in abstract classes and there is no way you can add such change in interface.

Answer (score 0):

> How all inheriting classes (i.e. Philips/Samsung/Videocon) will automatically get updated with the change?

They will suddenly become non-compileable, isn't that an update?

But I'd like to point out that there's in fact no difference between abstract method in abstract class and method in interface. Main difference lies in the fact that abstract classes can have methods with implementation and interfaces can not.

In fact, I'd say that I don't like MSDN definition and find it confusing and somewhat misleading.

Comment: So, shall I conclude that with following lines "By updating the base class, all inheriting classes are automatically updated with the change.", MSDN wants to stick with the implemented/concrete methods of abstract class?

Comment: I can't tell you what MSDN wants, because neither I am from MSDN nor the wording in article is precise. I'd rather not talk about inheritance in terms of "class is updated".