# Designing of classes with interface and abstract

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Hi Guys i am new to c#,
 I found the below answer from Microsoft, Recommendation for using the Interface and abstract.

If you anticipate creating multiple versions of your component, create an abstract class. Abstract classes provide a simple and easy way to version your components. By updating the base class, all inheriting classes are automatically updated with the change. Interfaces, on the other hand, cannot be changed once created. If a new version of an interface is required, you must create a whole new interface.

What do u mean Creating Multiple version of your component. can u please elaborate more providing example.

Comment: Question 2 should be a separate question. Here is a quick link to help you though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: I have removed question 2 because on Stack Overflow only one question is to be asked at a time (for good reason). Please ask it separately (better yet, Google it - it has been answered already!).

Comment: Search MSDN for  Create Multiple version component .net

Comment: see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700446/abstraction-vs-interface-confusion  Note: I think the "can't be changed" might be a COM holdover?  Seems odd in .NET.

Answer (score 4):

Having similar classes that share some sort of behaviour and/or properties are when you would use a base class. One of the canonical examples is shapes. You could something like this:

Base abstract class - FourSidedShape

- Has a GetPerimeter method that adds all four sides together.
- Has a GetArea method, that is abstract (must be defined by derived classes)

Derived class - Rectangle

- Automatically gets the GetPerimeter method for free
- Has to implement the GetArea method, using length x width

Derived class - Parallelogram

- Automatically gets the GetPerimeter method for free
- Has to implement the GetArea method, using base x height

Your derived classes can also add any unique behaviour they want that is not part of the base class.

NOTE: An abstract class is one that cannot be instatiated directly. You must use one of the derived classes.

Answer (score 3):

These really should be two questions, but I'll answer them both.

**Second one first**:   The usage of a nullable type is:

```
decimal? priceFromDb = datarow.Field<decimal?>("price");
```

In this case, you're declaring a type that will hold a decimal value, but could potentially be null, because, in this case it's coming from a database, and maybe the underlying field could be null.  The proper way to declare a nullable type is to use the `?` at the end of the type name.  Then, when you want to use the value in question, you would do something like:

```
if (priceFromDb.HasValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The price is {0}.", priceFromDb.Value);
}
```

**First question**:
An interface is used in C# to make sure a class or a struct implements some key feature you need.  They usually only contain handful of methods, usually no more than one or two, and the idea is that once you've created an published your interface, it's not going to change.  An abstract class, on the other other hand, gives you the ability to force classes to implement methods you need, as well as provide them with common functionality, and if you make changes to the abstract class in the future, like, add more common features, the inheriting classes get the features automatically.  Using an abstract class is not a license to put out breaking changes, it's just a way to combine common features into a class in a more clean function.  The best way I can describe is to use an abstract class to define the core attributes of your objects and its children, and use an interface to describe one key behavior of the class.

If you take a look at the .Net Framework, you'll see that most of the interfaces ([IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IComparable.aspx)) usually are used to enforce a behavior on the object, not its entire structure.

As an example, consider an abstract class vehicle:

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int NumWheels { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public abstract void Drive();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am a vehicle!";
    }
}
```

You could create a car object that inherits from Vehicle, and will need to implement `Drive()`, but will get the two properties `NumWheels` and `Name` for free.  Your inheriting class car could also overload `ToString()` if it wanted, or leave it as is:

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public override void Drive()
    {
        // your implementation here
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I am a car!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably "Difference Between abstract Class and Interface" is the most frequent question being asked in .Net world . I will explain the difference theoretically followed by code snippet.

Theoretically according to me, there are basically 5 differences between Abstract Class and Interface which are listed as below :-

1. A class can implement any number of interfaces but a subclass can at most use only one abstract class.
2. An abstract class can have non-abstract Methods(concrete methods) while in case of Interface all the methods has to be abstract.
3. An abstract class can declare or use any variables while an interface is not allowed to do so.
   So following Code will not compile :-

interface TestInterface

{

```
int x = 4;  // Filed Declaration in Interface 

void getMethod(); 

string getName();
```

}

abstract class TestAbstractClass

{

```
int i = 4; 
int k = 3; 
public abstract void getClassName();
```

}

It will generate a compile time error as :-

Error    1    Interfaces cannot contain fields .

So we need to omit Field Declaration in order to compile the code properly.

interface TestInterface

{

```
void getMethod();
string getName();
```

}

abstract class TestAbstractClass

{

```
int i = 4; 
int k = 3; 
public abstract void getClassName();
```

}

Above code compiles properly as no field declaration is there in Interface.

4.An abstract class can have constructor declaration while an interface can not do so.

So following code will not compile :-

interface TestInterface 
{

```
// Constructor Declaration 
public TestInterface() 
{ 
void getMethod(); 
string getName(); 
}
```

}

abstract class TestAbstractClass

{

```
public TestAbstractClass() 
{ 
int i = 4; 
int k = 3; 
public abstract void getClassName(); 
}
```

}

Above code will generate a compile time error as :-

Error    1    Interfaces cannot contain constructors

So we need to omit constructor declaration from interface in order to compile  our code .

Following code compiles perfectly :-

interface TestInterface 
{

```
void getMethod(); 
string getName();
```

}

abstract class TestAbstractClass 
{

```
public TestAbstractClass() 
{ 
int i = 4; 
int k = 3; 
public abstract void getClassName(); 

}
```

}

5.An abstract Class is allowed to have all access modifiers for all of its member declaration while in interface  we can not declare any access modifier(including public) as all the members of interface are implicitly public.

Note: Here I am talking about the access specifiers of the member of interface and not about the interface.

Following code will explain it better :-

It is perfectly legal to give provide access specifier as  Public (Remember only public is allowed)

public interface TestInterface

{

```
void getMethod(); 
string getName();
```

}

Above code compiles perfectly.

It is not allowed to give any access specifier to the members of the Interface.

interface TestInterface

{

```
public void getMethod(); 
public string getName();
```

}

Above code will generate a compile time error as :-

Error    1    The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item.

But the best way of declaring Interface will be to avoid access specifier on interface as well as members of interface.

interface Test

{

```
void getMethod(); 
string getName();
```

}